# Clearing intervals in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I'm trying to make the `setInterval` clear when a user types in the `off` command, how would I go about doing this? Basically, the user types the `on` command then then turn it off using the `off` command. This is a snippet of what I currently have.

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'on')) {
        var check = setInterval(test, 5000); 

    } else if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'off')) {
        clearInterval(test);

    }

    function test() {
    console.log('hello');

    }
}
```

Comment: declare check in global / higher scope.

Comment: `check`!=`test`. Also it won't be preserved across events when declared inside the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change code to

```
var check=null;
bot.on('message', (message) => {    
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'on')) {
        check = setInterval(test, 5000);     
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'off')) {
        clearInterval(check);    
    }

    function test() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```